# Pandas: Moving group titles to new columns

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

Environment - PY3.6, Jupyter Notebook:

```
import pandas as pd
import os
from IPython.display import display, HTML
```

I have an excel file that I've read into a dataframe. I've recreated the data programmatically here:

```
xl = [['group1'],
     ['john'],
     ['mike'],
     ['marry'],
     ['group2'],
     ['dan'],
     ['ann'],
     ['jacob'],
     ['susan']]
```

create a `pd.DataFrame()` and then `display` it.

```
s = pd.DataFrame(xl)
display(s)

    0
0   group1
1   john
2   mike
3   marry
4   group2
5   dan
6   ann
7   jacob
8   susan
```

The desired output is:

```
    0       1
0           group1
1   group1  john
2   group1  mike
3   group1  marry
4           group2
5   group2  dan
6   group2  ann
7   group2  jacob
8   group2  susan
```

I've tried several variations of `.melt()` but can only get that to work if the "group1" or "group2" is a column index.  I've also tried various forms of `.pivot()` and `.stack()`.  The `.stack` function seems to be the most promising, but it requires the DataFrame to be multi-indexed to work as I would hope.

My specific question is whether pandas has a function to accomplish this?

OR

Do i need to break the `df` down into component **groups** using the group names as column headers - then perform a `stack()` or `melt()` type function?

EDIT:  I suppose that I could also iterate over the rows - but this would be tricky as the "groups" are not always known.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIUC `str.contains` + `ffill`

```
df['1']=df['0'][df['0'].str.contains('group')]
df['1'].ffill(inplace=True)
df
Out[11]: 
        0       1
0  group1  group1
1    john  group1
2    mike  group1
3   marry  group1
4  group2  group2
5     dan  group2
6     ann  group2
7   jacob  group2
8   susan  group2
```

Comment: @jezrael Got it , If same thing happen to you let me know I will definitely help

Comment: Using the `.contains()` seems to be the key - the "group" headings are far more complex than the example and the `contains` method was able to parse correctly without any modification.  Thanks.

Comment: @BillA yep happy coding

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way - no guarantees about speed or elegance:

```
# Rename column to match desired output
df.columns = [1]

# Build a series with index=group_number, value=group_name
num2name = df[df[1].str.startswith('group')].reset_index(drop=True)

# Add column that indicates the group membership of each row, starting at 0
df[0] = df[1].str.startswith('group').cumsum() - 1

# Convert group numbers (0 onward) to group names ('groupN' starting from 1)
df[0].replace(group_rows, inplace=True)

df.sort_index(axis=1)
df
        0       1
0  group1  group1
1  group1    john
2  group1    mike
3  group1   marry
4  group2  group2
5  group2     dan
6  group2     ann
7  group2   jacob
8  group2   susan
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
# convert list to df
xl = pd.DataFrame(xl)

# extract words starting with group and fill the following blank values
xl['1'] = xl[0].str.findall('group.*').str[0].ffill()

# set value as NA where group is present in column 0
xl['1'] = xl.groupby('1')['1'].shift(1)

print(xl)

    0       1
0   group1  NaN
1   john    group1
2   mike    group1
3   marry   group1
4   group2  NaN
5   dan     group2
6   ann     group2
7   jacob   group2
8   susan   group2
```

Comment: I did get this to work, but for some reason on some of the "group" headings (much more complex data set) the `.findall()` wildcards were trickier to implement.  I would have thought that the conditions for the `.findall()` and `.contains()` would have been similar.